# What could be causing python script to loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright, I so here are the facts. I have 2 python scripts and I want Script1 to trigger Script2. I have tried the following ways to do this:

`from subprocess import call
 call(["python3", "script2.py"])`

The dreaded exec call:

`exec(open("script2.py").read())`

And finally:

`os.system("script2.py 1")`

So just to make sure I am giving you all the info needed. I want to run script1 first then once it is finished processing I want script1 to trigger script2. Currently no matter what I have tried, I get stuck in a loop where script one, just simply keeps running over and over again.

Any ideas?

Here is the actual code for script1:

```
import os

"""This looks like it is unnecessary but I can't include its context 
in this post. Just know it has an actual purpose."""
input_file = "gs://link_to_audio_file.m4a"

audio = input_file
output_format = os.path.basename(input_file).replace("m4a", "flac")

os.system('ffmpeg -i %s -ar 16000 -ac 1 %s' % (audio,output_format))


os.system("python3 script2.py")
```

Comment: Then one of your scripts must have an infinite loop. I can't tell you anything, as not enough information was provided.

Comment: could you add more info?

Comment: If script2 is written the right way, script1 just has to `import` it.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious -- did you think we would be able to diagnose the problem without seeing script1?

Comment: @JohnGordon no I knew it would be hard but was hoping your responses might spark some ideas, but alas they didn’t. Oh well, I may have a couple of solutions going to give them a try and just remove this question. Also to address the information side, this is all I could provide, company I am working with did not want me to post the actual script even though it was just a simple audio encoder.

Comment: A good first step in figuring out issues like this is to simplify the script by taking out all the business logic (in this case, audio encoding stuff), leaving just the overall structure and flow of the script, which is likely where the problem lies.  This gives you a much smaller piece of code to look at, which might be enough to reveal the issue.  And if not, the remaining code can probably be posted to a forum such as this one without revealing any business secrets.

Comment: This is purely a guess, but do you have the names of the scripts confused?  i.e. script1 invokes _itself_ instead of invoking script2?

Comment: @JohnGordon was able to add the basics of the script

Comment: I think after much research I have solved it. When `os.system('ffmpeg -i %s -ar 16000 -ac 1 %s' % (audio,output_format))` is running it is then basically performing a SystemExit. Then the script starts from the beginning again. Which is what is causing the loop. Now the real question is how to I either 1) keep it from starting over again or 2 how do I keep it from performing SystemExit, or better is there another way to run a terminal command in a script that doesn't involve the SystemExit all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the first script runs cleanly by itself by commenting out the call to the second script.  If it still seems to run forever there's an issue other than trying to call a second script.  If you have a IDE, you can step through the code to discover where it hangs.  If you're not using an IDE, place print statements in the script so you can see the execution path.  Do you possibly have a cyclic call?  So the first python script is calling the second and the second python script is in turn calling the first?

Answer (score 0):

When using os.system, I believe you'd need to include python as in

```
os.system("python script2.py 1")
```

I can't tell why you're in a loop without seeing the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this issue! I was actually using an import statement in the second script that was trying to import a variable from the first script, but instead it was importing the entire script, causing it to run in an endless loop. Just like LAS had suggested, nicely done! Thank you all for all your help on this!